# What is a 'civcuck'

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, etymology

Context:

> By having us all take up barbarism the Right is spared from the
> civcuck middling elements having too much a say...
>
> <sup>[*Source*](https://froudesociety.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/why-bapism-why-now/)</sup>

I am curious about the word *civcuck*. I cannot find it in any dictionaries (even Urban Dictionary), nor can I find any background information on it anywhere. I gather that it is not something to be used in polite company (or at all), but what does it mean and what is its etymology?

Comment: Excellent question—never seen this word before, and it’s surprisingly difficult to find any information on it. The _civ_ part seems to be from _civil_ (though I’m not sure which sense) or _civic_ or _civilian_. The _cuck_ part is probably related to [_cuckservative_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckservative) (a derogatory portmanteau of _cuckold_ and _conservative_). I don’t know what exactly a civil/civic/civilian conservative might be, specifically. It doesn’t seem to be particularly high praise, though, nor something to be uttered in polite society.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quote seems to be from the ravings on this site: https://froudesociety.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/why-bapism-why-now/

'cuck' is a supposedly unfriendly monicker for everyone perceived to be 'self-confessed conservative - but really not' or something of the sort, it's etymology is muddled and full of weirdness. It mostly is used as an insult/touchstone.
'civ' in this context probably refers to 'civilized' in contrast to the 'barbarianism' that is espoused.
'civcuck' thereby is a meld of the two words above.

As neither conservative, civilized, barbarian, or actually any of the longer words employed are used in their usual meaning, the overall context as well as the specific word in question are extremely open to interpretation, which might be the intention.

For etymology of cuck: [Source and popularity of the recent slang word "cuck"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343841/source-and-popularity-of-the-recent-slang-word-cuck)

Comment: Thank you, I found it! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckservative

Comment: I’ve edited the source into the question (where it needs to be), so you can remove it from your answer if you want.